# Combining CSV files in Powershell - different headings

Tags: powershell

I need to take a slew of csv files from a directory and get them into an array in Powershell (to eventually manipulate and write back to a CSV).

The problem is there are 5 file types.  I need around 8 columns from each. The columns are essentially the same, but have different headings.

Is there an easy way to do this?  I started creating a custom object with my 8 fields, looping through the files importing each one, looking at the filename (which tells me the column names I need) and then a bunch of ifs to add it to my custom object array.

I was wondering if there is a simpler way...like with a template saying which columns from each file.

Comment: I'm not gonna bug you about code for this particular question (at this point anyway) since you seem to wanna move away from what you already have but... atleast you could show us some header examples? Are the CSV:s identical apart from the different headers? Are the columns lined up in the same fashion for all CSV:s but just with different column names?

Comment: No, the columns vary by file format. Some have more, some less and the columns I need don't appear in the same place (like column 3) in each file.      I was thinking if I could create an array of arrays with the column names from each file type or something and use that.   The column names are not repeated across files so say I need column "TTAcct" from file format 1, there is no "TTAcct" in any of the other file formats so I don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Give us an example of a file name or two, or explain that better. Such as, do they include the headers in the name? Do all files that start with 'Yellow' have the same headers? I think a Switch statement, some RegEx, and custom objects made with a `Select` statement or in a `ForEach-Object` loop could make short work of this.

Answer (score 0):

wound up doing this. It may have not been the most efficient, but works. I wound up writing out each file separately and combining at the end as PS really got bogged down (over a million rows combined).

```
$Newcsv = @()

$path = "c:\scrap\BWFILES\"

$files = gci -path $path -recurse  -filter *.csv | Where-Object { !    ($_.psiscontainer) } 

$counter=1 

foreach($file in $files)
{

$csv = Import-Csv $file.FullName
if ($file.Name -like '*SAV*')
    {    

    $Newcsv = $csv | Select-Object @{Name="PRODUCT";Expression={"SV"}},DMBRCH,DMACCT,DMSHRT 
    }

if ($file.Name -like '*TIME*')
    {    

    $Newcsv = $csv | Select-Object @{Name="PRODUCT";Expression={"TM"}},TMBRCH,TMACCT,TMSHRT 
    }
if ($file.Name -like '*TRAN*')
    {    

    $Newcsv = $csv | Select-Object @{Name="PRODUCT";Expression={"TR"}},DMBRCH,DMACCT,DMSHRT 
    }    

if ($file.Name -like '*LN*')
    {    

    $Newcsv = $csv | Select-Object @{Name="PRODUCT";Expression={"LN"}},LNBRCH,LNNOTE,LNSHRT 
    }    

    $Newcsv | Export-Csv "C:\scrap\$file.name$counter.csv" -force -notypeinformation
    $counter++

}
    get-childItem "c:\scrap\*.csv" | foreach {
    $filePath = $_

    $lines =  $lines = Get-Content $filePath  
    $linesToWrite = switch($getFirstLine) {
          $true  {$lines}
          $false {$lines | Select -Skip 1}

    }

$getFirstLine = $false
Add-Content "c:\scrap\combined.csv" $linesToWrite
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a hashtable for reference, a little RegEx matching, and using the automatic variable `$Matches` in a `ForEach-Object` loop (alias `%` used) that could all be shortened to:

```
$path = "c:\scrap\BWFILES\"

$Reference = @{
'SAV' = 'SV'
'TIME' = 'TM'
'TRAN' = 'TR'
'LN'='LN'
}

Set-Content -Value "PRODUCT,BRCH,ACCT,SHRT" -Path 'c:\scrap\combined.csv'

gci -path $path -recurse  -filter *.csv | Where-Object { !($_.psiscontainer) -and $_.Name -match ".*(SAV|TIME|TRAN|LN).*"}|%{
    $Product = $Reference[($Matches[1])]
    Import-CSV $_.FullName | Select-Object @{Name="PRODUCT";Expression={$Product}},*BRCH,@{l='Acct';e={$_.LNNOTE, $_.DMACCT, $_.TMACCT|?{$_}}},*SHRT | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select -Skip 1 | Add-Content 'c:\scrap\combined.csv'
}
```

That should produce the exact same file. Only kind of tricky part was the LNNOTE/TMACCT/DMACCT field since obviously you can't just do the same as like *SHRT.